# Create the entities programmatically in core data model in iPhone during runtime

Tags: ios, core-data, entities

I want to create the entities in core data model during runtime programmatically  in iPhone application . I don't know how to create custom entities during runtime . plz help me .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Apple documentation has numerous, extensive examples of doing this.  Please search in Xcode for 'Core Data'.  Example code: iPhoneCoreDataRecipes, CoreDataBooks, ThreadedCoreData